# Install windows 8 via VHD from windows 7 bootcamp on Macbook

Tags: windows, osx-lion, vhd, boot-camp

I know this is crazy, so hear it out.

I am interested in installing windows 8 on my Macbook. I already have windows 7 installed via bootcamp from Mountain Lion. Has anyone successfully installed windows 8 using a vhd on windows 7 that is bootcamped from mountain lion? I have had issues before and wanted to hear first hand before wrecking my setup..again.

If so, what did you do or what tutorial did you follow? I already googled for a while with no straight forward answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2393-windows-8-vhd-create-boot-dual-boot.html

To configure boot camp on Windows 8, you have to use a trick to access the boot camp control panel:

- create "BootCampControlPanel.cmd" file
- edit this file by adding the unique following line: runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "C:\Windows\System32\AppleControlPanel.exe"
- create a shortcut to this file
- right click on this shortcut (since your boot camp is not configured, you may have to use an external mouse to be able to right click or you can put two fingers on your trackpad and click) and select Properties. Then click on the "Advanced..." button and tick "Run as administrator"

Everytime you want to access the boot camp control panel, you just have to double click on this shortcut :)